# JavaScript regex which forces domain name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I am using AngularJS's form validation and have the following e-mail input

```
<input type="email" />
```

This uses the AngularJS email regex validation but it still allows invalid emails

Example the following e-mail should be invalid but is passing as valid:
test@test

I need to create a regex (ng-pattern) that forces a domain.
eg name@domian.com

I also want the regex to allow custom domains like name@custom.name

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript?rq=1

Comment: Andrew, the duplicate question you pointed to does not answer my question of forcing a domain in the regex. I want to force a .com etc.. those regexs still allow test@test

Comment: find your own regex and use `ng-pattern` on a text input. *"email regex"* has tons and tons of results in a web search ... or if you have a server side one do remote validation

Comment: charliettifl, please point me to a web search result that answers my question of forcing a domain in the email. I couldn't find a result which is why I asked on here.